# Adding custom weights to training data in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Is it possible to add custom weights to the training instances in PyTorch? More explicitly, I'd like to add a custom weight for every row in my dataset. By default, the weights are 1, which means every data is equally important for my model.

Comment: You could look at torch.nn.init [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html). You could maybe do `torch.nn.init(layer.weight, a)`. I don't know if that is what you mean though

Comment: @DwightFoster This one seems about initializing model weights. So not related, sadly.

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to penalize the loss function, there is a place for you to specify weights directly there. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

Comment: @JohnStud Multiplying the loss function would have the same effect as weighing instances, so that should work. However, can't I do this by modifying my training dataset, rather than specifying weights for each time I train stuff?

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it more explicit regarding the outcome you want?

Comment: Given the update, the loss function weighting is exactly what you want to use.

Comment: @JohnStud I understand weighting loss function has the same effect, but it requires me to modify the code, rather than the dataset. Being able to add weights to dataset explicitly would be simpler for me. So, I'm wondering if it's possible to do so. Meanwhile, I'm using loss weighting.

Comment: So if you just want to fix the parameters of the weights, there are two ways to achieve that: First, you can define a linear layer, init the weights as 1, and fix it by no gradient. The second way is that: while the linear layer is just a matrix between your data and weight matrix, you can simply set an all-one-matrix and multiply them (feel free to add activation function after it). I guess both ways can get what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loss functions support class weights not sample weights. For sample weights you can do something like below (commented inline):

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(8, 4)
# Ground truth
y = torch.randint(2, (8,))
# Weights per sample 
weights = torch.rand(8, 1) 

# Add weights as a columns, so that it will be passed trough
# dataloaders in case you want to use one
x = torch.cat((x, weights), dim=1)

model = torch.nn.Linear(4, 2)

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
def weighted_loss(y, y_hat, w):
  return (loss_fn(y, y_hat)*w).mean()

loss = weighted_loss(model(x[:, :-1]), y, x[:, -1])
print (loss)
```

Comment: This looks like the logical thing to do. Thanks a lot!